# How use PTAB API

Tags: api

Does anyone have step by step instructions on how to use the PTAB API? Patentsview is easy since you can just download decisions (or the document that each line devoted to each case) into csv or dta format. The API instructions don't say anything about how you can see your data unless they are presuming you do something in Python.

I want to be able to bulk download PTAB decisions and the chart in the spreadsheet they show in the website which looks like an Excel file with each row having info on each PTAB proceeding. Once I put in dates I get a URL. What then happens next? Also I was informed by someone that this is limited to 500 at a time so do you have to keep on doing this or if you wanted to download the information for a few years? I want to see the PTAB spreadsheet and put it in CSV format to be able to use in R or Stata.

I also want to be able to bulk download PTAB decisions and maybe certian types of documents.

Comment: Do you know how to program? If not you will probably need to learn how to.

Comment: API stands for Application Programming Interface. It provides a means for accessing a computer program or data source using a programming language. It may be that there are software products out there that utilize the PTAB data, but otherwise you are going to have to write your own program. While Python is a good choice of programming language, virtually any language would work for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `patent_client`! It's a python module that searches the live USPTO and EPO databases using a Django-style API, and supports PTAB queries. The results from any query can then be cast into pandas DataFrames or Series with a simple `.to_pandas()` call.

```
from patent_client import PtabProceeding

# Get a proceeding
trial = PtabProceeding.objects.get("IPR2018-00001")

# View documents
trial.documents.to_pandas()

# Download all documents
for doc in trial.documents:
    doc.download()
```

A great place to start is the [User Guide Introduction](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/)

[image: Patent Client Logo]

[PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/parkerhancock/patent_client) | [Docs](https://patent-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

(Full disclosure - I'm the author and maintainer of patent_client)

Comment: Although relevant to the question it is not exactly an answer to the question and although you acknowledge that you are the author, it looks a little commercial. No SE site allows signatures partially to avoid the type of large logo type displays. It would be a good idea to edit your recent answers to remove those.